# Combine @property with another decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-decorators

I have these decorators that work with `@property`

```
def android(**params):
    def deco(f):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if is_android:
                return params
            return f()
        return wrap
    return deco

def ios(**params):
    def deco(f):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if not is_android:
                return params
            return f()
        return wrap
    return deco
```

And defined class:

```
class Foo:
    @property
    @android(foo=1)
    @ios(foo=2)
    def foo(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
print(f.foo)
```

I have to repeat again and again the `@property` every time I want to use. Is there any way to combine the `@property` into `@android` and `@ios`? I mean just need to use `@android` and `@ios` without `@property` but I am able to call `f.foo`

Comment: Are you sure these work as expected at all? The indentation seems off and it doesn't return the inner functions... which throws `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` on my computer.

Comment: I edit the code a little bit. On my computer, the code worked.

Comment: If it works, what exactly does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a class decorator that modify your class to make properties be Class fields.

```
is_android = True


def android(**params):
    def deco(f):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if is_android:
                return params
            return f()

        wrap.__decorated_by_mobile__ = True
        return wrap

    return deco


def ios(**params):
    def deco(f):
        f.wrapped = True

        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if not is_android:
                return params
            return f()

        wrap.__decorated_by_mobile__ = True
        return wrap

    return deco


def class_deco(cls):
    for name, method in cls.__dict__.items():
        if callable(method):
            if hasattr(method, '__decorated_by_mobile__'):
                setattr(cls, name, method())
    return cls


@class_deco
class Foo:
    @android(a=1)
    @ios(a=2)
    def foo(self):
        pass


f = Foo()
print(f.foo)
```

Hope this is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the decorators to return a `property` object. Though, unless you only want to support a single specific order for them, you'll need to make their logic a bit more complicated so that they will work even if the "function" they're being applied to is already a property object. Here's an untested update of one of your decorators that I think should do it:

```
def android(**params):
    def deco(f):
        if isinstance(f, property):
            prop = f.getter
            f = f.fget
        else:
            prop = property
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if is_android:
                return params
            return f()
        return prop(wrap)
    return deco
```

But I'm not sure that's really the best approach. Your code doesn't ever use the `foo` function you decorate. One of the decorators always intercepts the call. If that's true of your real code, I'd suggest writing your own descriptor type and not bothering with `property` or decorators at all. Here's a fairly simple example of a custom descriptor that takes the values to return in the android and IOS cases as arguments (and it's use in a class):

```
class MyDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, android_value, ios_value):
        self.android_value = android_value
        self.ios_value = ios_value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner)
        if is_android:
            return self.android_value
        else:
            return self.ios_value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Foo:
    foo = MyDescriptor({"foo": 1}, {"foo": 2})
```

You could even go further towards simplifying things if the `is_android` value is a constant and if you will know its value at the time the class is being defined. In that situation, you can just assign a normal class variable, using conditional logic to modify the value as necessary:

```
class Foo:
    foo = {"foo": 1 if is_android else 2}
```

Comment: Your solution was what I did before. I defined a function that had android and ios params. Then return. However, it was hard to read. That was why I came up with `@property`